# Swift Decodable parse part of JSON

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to parse a json that looks like this using decodable:

```
    {
    "count": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "title": 1,
            "content": "Bla"
        } ]
    }
```

My problem is that I don't want to make a class that has a count property just to be able to use the decoder. I want to parse only the results part I don't care about the count.

So my question is, can decodable.decode somehow only parse a part of the result json. I mean a certain key path instead of the whole json ? And I want to do it using Decodable.

In a nutshell I don't want this:

```
class IncidentWrapper: Codable{
    var count: Int
    var incident: [Incident]
}
```

What I would Imagine is to have this:

```
decodable.decode([Incident].self, from: response.data, forKey: "results")
```

Thanks

Comment: You could write a custom decoder to conform to `Decodable` but in my opinion getting the decoding code for free more than makes up for the need to declare one small struct. You don't even have to expose that struct to the rest of your app; You can simply expose `root.results` rather than `root` from your network fetch operation

Comment: Honestly it's usually easier just to make a wrapper struct. Is there a particular reason why you don't want to?

Answer (score 3):

let me see what I can suggest:

```swift
struct Result: Codeable {
   var id: Int
   var message: String
   var color: String
   var type: String

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case results
   }

   enum NestedResultKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case id, message, color, type
   }
}

extension Result: Decodable {
   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let result = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

      let nestedResult = try result.nestedContainer(keyedBy: NestedResultKeys.self, forKey: .result)
      id = try nestedResult.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
      message = try nestedResult.decode(String.self, forKey: .message)
      color = try nestedResult.decode(String.self, forKey: .color)
      type = try nestedResult.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
   }
}
```

See this documentation for more insight

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/encoding_decoding_and_serialization

Hope it helps your project!

Answer (score 2):

You can define a generic wrapper for once and use everywhere.

It will work as a generic wrapper for results key only.

```
protocol ResultsDecodable: Decodable{
    associatedtype T: Decodable
    var results: [T] {get}
}

struct Result<Element: Decodable>: ResultsDecodable{
    typealias T = Element
    var results: [Element]
}
```

Extend JSONDecoder to get results output.

```
  extension JSONDecoder {
        func resultDecode<T>(_ type: Result<T>.Type, from data: Data) throws -> [T] where T : Decodable{
            let model = try! decode(type, from: data)
            return model.results
        }
    }
```

And use like this

```
var str = #"{"count": 1,"results": [{"title": 1,"content": "Bla"}, {"title": 2,"content": "Bla"} ]}"#

class Incident: Decodable{
    let title: Int
    let content: String
}

let indicents = (try! JSONDecoder().resultDecode(Result<Incident>.self, from: str.data(using: .utf8)!))
```

See how it makes everything more complex. BETTER USE IncidentWrapper!!!

Comment: This is by far the most convincing answer I have ever got on Stackoverflow  Thanks for that, IncidentWrapper it is 

Answer (score 1):

You probably is looking for `JSONSerialization` class. This is an example how it works:

```
    if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any] {
        if let results = json["results"] as? [Incident] {
            print(results.count)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but Im searching for the solution using decodable

Comment: Decodable works only with structs or classes. If you want to decode the data manually, you should use JSONSerialization instead

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use the keys you care about.  Just leave off the count.  Don't make it part of your struct.

You will only get errors if you can't find a key in the json that you are expecting in the struct.  You can avoid this too, though, if you make it an optional in the struct.

Comment: but that would make me have a wrapper class, that would have only results. I want to create a decodable class with the results property without a parent empty class