# using a part of json for decoding in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, api

I want to decode only a part of json string with or without decoder in Swift.
My API Response is

```
{
        "title": "Recent Uploads tagged kitten",
        "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/tags\/kitten\/",
        "description": "",
        "modified": "2020-06-29T11:11:29Z",
        "generator": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com",
        "items": [
       {
            "title": "Sur le qui-vive, mais pas trop ...",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/nf39\/50057255053\/",
            "media": {"m":"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50057255053_dccf68d9ee_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2020-06-20T17:40:34-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/nf39\/\">Titole<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/nf39\/50057255053\/\" title=\"Sur le qui-vive, mais pas trop ...\"><img src=\"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50057255053_dccf68d9ee_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"240\" alt=\"Sur le qui-vive, mais pas trop ...\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>\u201cCelui qui a confiance en lui m\u00e8nera les autres.\u201d<br \/> Horace<br \/> <br \/> <b>Thank you very much for your comments and for your faves.<\/b><br \/> (Please do not use without my written permission.)<\/p>",
            "published": "2020-06-29T11:11:29Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"Titole\")",
            "author_id": "46348076@N08",
            "tags": "kitten cat gatto katze kat gato titole nicolefaton squareformat grey"
       },
       {
            "title": "baby cat",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/dimitra_daby\/50057281506\/",
            "media": {"m":"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50057281506_ba2bb9ba16_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2020-06-29T10:05:21-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/dimitra_daby\/\">Love me tender \u266a\u00b8.\u2022*\u00b4\u00a8\u00b4\u00a8*\u2022.\u266a\u00b8.\u2022*\u00b4<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/dimitra_daby\/50057281506\/\" title=\"baby cat\"><img src=\"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50057281506_ba2bb9ba16_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"baby cat\" \/><\/a><\/p> ",
            "published": "2020-06-29T07:06:20Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"Love me tender \u266a\u00b8.\u2022*\u00b4\u00a8\u00b4\u00a8*\u2022.\u266a\u00b8.\u2022*\u00b4\")",
            "author_id": "67833313@N08",
            "tags": "cat animals white kitten minimal mikrolimano piraeus greece dimitrakirgiannaki photography nikond3100 nature brown"
       },
       {
            "title": "baby cat",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/dimitra_daby\/50057527087\/",
            "media": {"m":"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50057527087_40eee01398_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2020-06-29T10:05:21-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/dimitra_daby\/\">Love me tender \u266a\u00b8.\u2022*\u00b4\u00a8\u00b4\u00a8*\u2022.\u266a\u00b8.\u2022*\u00b4<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/dimitra_daby\/50057527087\/\" title=\"baby cat\"><img src=\"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50057527087_40eee01398_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"baby cat\" \/><\/a><\/p> ",
            "published": "2020-06-29T07:06:19Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"Love me tender \u266a\u00b8.\u2022*\u00b4\u00a8\u00b4\u00a8*\u2022.\u266a\u00b8.\u2022*\u00b4\")",
            "author_id": "67833313@N08",
            "tags": "cat animals white kitten minimal mikrolimano piraeus greece dimitrakirgiannaki photography nikond3100 nature blackandwhite"
       },
       {
            "title": "Mom with her kitty \ud83d\udc9e",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/andrea_yoly\/50057233161\/",
            "media": {"m":"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50057233161_4fcb9429e1_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2020-06-14T07:50:11-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/andrea_yoly\/\">En memoria de Zarpazos, mi valiente y mimoso tigre<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/andrea_yoly\/50057233161\/\" title=\"Mom with her kitty \ud83d\udc9e\"><img src=\"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50057233161_4fcb9429e1_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"156\" alt=\"Mom with her kitty \ud83d\udc9e\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>Mam\u00e1 con su gatito \ud83d\udc9e<\/p>",
            "published": "2020-06-29T06:47:59Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"En memoria de Zarpazos, mi valiente y mimoso tigre\")",
            "author_id": "38941615@N02",
            "tags": "blackcat tabbykitten catbreastfeeding cats kitten love motherandson"
       },
       {
            "title": "A Cat in the Hand is Worth . . .",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/bkhagar_gallery\/50056346628\/",
            "media": {"m":"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50056346628_6c24fcca5c_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2020-04-22T17:29:06-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/bkhagar_gallery\/\">BKHagar *Kim*<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/bkhagar_gallery\/50056346628\/\" title=\"A Cat in the Hand is Worth . . .\"><img src=\"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50056346628_6c24fcca5c_m.jpg\" width=\"191\" height=\"240\" alt=\"A Cat in the Hand is Worth . . .\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>Well, you can draw your own conclusions. We LOVE our cats! LOL! :)<\/p>",
            "published": "2020-06-29T04:16:07Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"BKHagar *Kim*\")",
            "author_id": "34106278@N04",
            "tags": "bkhagar cat kitty kitten hand porcelain"
       },
       {
            "title": "My baby Kitten \"Kiki\"",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/188970647@N05\/50056784831\/",
            "media": {"m":"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50056784831_db1436196b_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2020-02-19T22:56:53-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/188970647@N05\/\">arel.in<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/188970647@N05\/50056784831\/\" title=\"My baby Kitten &quot;Kiki&quot;\"><img src=\"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50056784831_db1436196b_m.jpg\" width=\"180\" height=\"240\" alt=\"My baby Kitten &quot;Kiki&quot;\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>smart<\/p>",
            "published": "2020-06-29T03:15:26Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"arel.in\")",
            "author_id": "188970647@N05",
            "tags": "animals kitten"
       },
       {
            "title": "Tiny Jane",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/14461370@N03\/50055707913\/",
            "media": {"m":"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50055707913_d590433c3a_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2020-06-28T18:12:41-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/14461370@N03\/\">zimwizdotcom<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/14461370@N03\/50055707913\/\" title=\"Tiny Jane\"><img src=\"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50055707913_d590433c3a_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"Tiny Jane\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>It seems my little Jane will forever stay tiny. Malnourished after being abandoned I suspect it stunted her growth when she was developing. But it hasn't slowed her down as she can run faster than any animal her size. And she has more love than so many animals much, much bigger than her.<br \/> <br \/> 20mm f\/3.5 Nikkor-UD @ f\/3.5 (wide open)<\/p>",
            "published": "2020-06-29T00:01:52Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"zimwizdotcom\")",
            "author_id": "14461370@N03",
            "tags": "20mmf35nikkorud 20mm 20mf35 nikkor nikkorud cat jane kitten smallcat dirtywindow"
       },
       {
            "title": "Kitten \u5b50\u732b",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50056316582\/",
            "media": {"m":"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50056316582_4e492c0ea6_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2020-06-25T13:21:06-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/eriko-japan\/\">eriko_jpn<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50056316582\/\" title=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\"><img src=\"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50056316582_4e492c0ea6_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"180\" alt=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>OLYMPUS DIGITAL CAMERA<\/p>",
            "published": "2020-06-28T22:32:56Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"eriko_jpn\")",
            "author_id": "52742772@N02",
            "tags": "cat kitten"
       },
       {
            "title": "Kitten \u5b50\u732b",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50056076841\/",
            "media": {"m":"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50056076841_6dd3bfb97f_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2020-06-25T13:20:15-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/eriko-japan\/\">eriko_jpn<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50056076841\/\" title=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\"><img src=\"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50056076841_6dd3bfb97f_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"180\" alt=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>OLYMPUS DIGITAL CAMERA<\/p>",
            "published": "2020-06-28T22:32:52Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"eriko_jpn\")",
            "author_id": "52742772@N02",
            "tags": "cat kitten"
       },
       {
            "title": "Kitten \u5b50\u732b",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50056317592\/",
            "media": {"m":"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50056317592_a60109696e_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2020-06-25T13:20:54-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/eriko-japan\/\">eriko_jpn<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50056317592\/\" title=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\"><img src=\"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50056317592_a60109696e_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"180\" alt=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>OLYMPUS DIGITAL CAMERA<\/p>",
            "published": "2020-06-28T22:32:55Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"eriko_jpn\")",
            "author_id": "52742772@N02",
            "tags": "cat kitten"
       },
       {
            "title": "Kitten \u5b50\u732b",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50055484608\/",
            "media": {"m":"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50055484608_3a0c1614b2_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2020-06-26T09:45:00-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/eriko-japan\/\">eriko_jpn<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50055484608\/\" title=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\"><img src=\"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50055484608_3a0c1614b2_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"171\" alt=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>OLYMPUS DIGITAL CAMERA<\/p>",
            "published": "2020-06-28T22:33:00Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"eriko_jpn\")",
            "author_id": "52742772@N02",
            "tags": "cat kitten"
       },
       {
            "title": "Kitten \u5b50\u732b",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50055487838\/",
            "media": {"m":"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50055487838_dd74230bda_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2020-06-26T09:44:39-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/eriko-japan\/\">eriko_jpn<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50055487838\/\" title=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\"><img src=\"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50055487838_dd74230bda_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"180\" alt=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>OLYMPUS DIGITAL CAMERA<\/p>",
            "published": "2020-06-28T22:32:59Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"eriko_jpn\")",
            "author_id": "52742772@N02",
            "tags": "cat kitten"
       },
       {
            "title": "Kitten \u5b50\u732b",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50055485638\/",
            "media": {"m":"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50055485638_7ba0b79d3a_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2020-06-26T09:43:59-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/eriko-japan\/\">eriko_jpn<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50055485638\/\" title=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\"><img src=\"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50055485638_7ba0b79d3a_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"206\" alt=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>OLYMPUS DIGITAL CAMERA<\/p>",
            "published": "2020-06-28T22:33:02Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"eriko_jpn\")",
            "author_id": "52742772@N02",
            "tags": "cat kitten"
       },
       {
            "title": "Kitten \u5b50\u732b",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50056313792\/",
            "media": {"m":"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50056313792_016db8365b_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2020-06-25T13:21:11-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/eriko-japan\/\">eriko_jpn<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50056313792\/\" title=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\"><img src=\"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50056313792_016db8365b_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"180\" alt=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>OLYMPUS DIGITAL CAMERA<\/p>",
            "published": "2020-06-28T22:32:57Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"eriko_jpn\")",
            "author_id": "52742772@N02",
            "tags": "cat kitten"
       },
       {
            "title": "Kitten \u5b50\u732b",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50056306567\/",
            "media": {"m":"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50056306567_a70f3c7323_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2020-06-26T09:45:08-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/eriko-japan\/\">eriko_jpn<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50056306567\/\" title=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\"><img src=\"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50056306567_a70f3c7323_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"180\" alt=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>OLYMPUS DIGITAL CAMERA<\/p>",
            "published": "2020-06-28T22:33:00Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"eriko_jpn\")",
            "author_id": "52742772@N02",
            "tags": "cat kitten"
       },
       {
            "title": "Kitten \u5b50\u732b",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50055485163\/",
            "media": {"m":"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50055485163_5bdbf0d8b2_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2020-06-26T09:44:11-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/eriko-japan\/\">eriko_jpn<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50055485163\/\" title=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\"><img src=\"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50055485163_5bdbf0d8b2_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"180\" alt=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>OLYMPUS DIGITAL CAMERA<\/p>",
            "published": "2020-06-28T22:33:03Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"eriko_jpn\")",
            "author_id": "52742772@N02",
            "tags": "cat kitten"
       },
       {
            "title": "Kitten \u5b50\u732b",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50056318287\/",
            "media": {"m":"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50056318287_f6c1fd2739_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2020-06-25T13:20:39-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/eriko-japan\/\">eriko_jpn<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50056318287\/\" title=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\"><img src=\"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50056318287_f6c1fd2739_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"171\" alt=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>OLYMPUS DIGITAL CAMERA<\/p>",
            "published": "2020-06-28T22:32:54Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"eriko_jpn\")",
            "author_id": "52742772@N02",
            "tags": "cat kitten"
       },
       {
            "title": "Kitten \u5b50\u732b",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50055486148\/",
            "media": {"m":"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50055486148_379be7598d_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2020-06-26T09:43:57-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/eriko-japan\/\">eriko_jpn<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50055486148\/\" title=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\"><img src=\"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50055486148_379be7598d_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"180\" alt=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>OLYMPUS DIGITAL CAMERA<\/p>",
            "published": "2020-06-28T22:33:01Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"eriko_jpn\")",
            "author_id": "52742772@N02",
            "tags": "cat kitten"
       },
       {
            "title": "Kitten \u5b50\u732b",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50055497758\/",
            "media": {"m":"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50055497758_cac1374fb1_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2020-06-25T13:20:30-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/eriko-japan\/\">eriko_jpn<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50055497758\/\" title=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\"><img src=\"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50055497758_cac1374fb1_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"180\" alt=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>OLYMPUS DIGITAL CAMERA<\/p>",
            "published": "2020-06-28T22:32:54Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"eriko_jpn\")",
            "author_id": "52742772@N02",
            "tags": "cat kitten"
       },
       {
            "title": "Kitten \u5b50\u732b",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50056323122\/",
            "media": {"m":"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50056323122_4306467c0c_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2020-06-25T13:20:20-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/eriko-japan\/\">eriko_jpn<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/eriko-japan\/50056323122\/\" title=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\"><img src=\"https:\/\/live.staticflickr.com\/65535\/50056323122_4306467c0c_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"Kitten \u5b50\u732b\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>OLYMPUS DIGITAL CAMERA<\/p>",
            "published": "2020-06-28T22:32:52Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"eriko_jpn\")",
            "author_id": "52742772@N02",
            "tags": "cat kitten"
       }
        ]
}
```

From this response, I need the items part only. Further in that, the "media" is another JSON. So I do not want to make a separate Struct for each type of JSON. It would be really helpful if I can use something like dictionary from my JSON Data to instantiate my class objects.

P.S.- I referred to [Swift Decodable parse part of JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61197991/swift-decodable-parse-part-of-json) and this post pretty much addresses the same problem. However, the code given in one of the answers,

```
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String:Any]
```

does not work for me. Here `data` is my API response.

when I print `json` variable, I get `nil`

Comment: Don't use `try?`, specially not when developing new code, because you are ignoring the error that contains information on why the decoding fails.

Comment: I recommend you switch to using the `Codable` protocol, instead of the older `JSONSerialization`. You can paste your json in https://app.quicktype.io, and it will generate the struct and decoding code for you. You can just leave out the properties in your struct that you don't want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Codable`. Create a decodable struct model corresponding to your JSON like this:

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    var items: [Item]
}

struct Item: Decodable {
    let title, link: String
    let media: Media
    let dateTaken, description, published, author: String
    let authorId, tags: String
}

struct Media: Codable {
    let m: String
}
```

Instead of `JSONSerialization` use `JSONDecoder` like this:

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let items = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data).items
    print(items)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Modified the `JSONDecoder` with `keyDecodingStrategy` credits: @Vadian.